# How to run an array against another array where each number in both get iterated against each other?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

I'm attempting to solve a [freeCodeCamp challenge](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/intermediate-algorithm-scripting/smallest-common-multiple) that has been stumping me for much of this week.

I would like help and guidance with specific things but not necessarily a complete solution to the freeCodeCamp challenge.

The problem is as follows:

> ### Intermediate Algorithm Scripting: Smallest Common Multiple
>
> Find the smallest common multiple of the provided parameters that can be evenly divided by both, as well as by all sequential numbers in the range between these parameters.
>
> The range will be an array of two numbers that will not necessarily be in numerical order.
>
> For example, if given 1 and 3, find the smallest common multiple of both 1 and 3 that is also evenly divisible by all numbers between 1 and 3. The answer here would be 6.

This is what I have so far:

```
function smallestCommons(arr) {
    var sortedArr = arr.sort(function (a, b) { return a - b });
    var startingPoint = sortedArr[0]; var endingPoint = sortedArr[1];

    var arrRange = []; // contains numbers from startingPoint to 
                       // endingPoint thanks to for loop

    for (var i = startingPoint; i < endingPoint + 1; i++) {
        arrRange.push(i);
    }
}
smallestCommons([1, 5]);
```

My game plan is to have another for loop that runs through a huge numbers range and each number in that huge numbers range goes through a condition that checks if each number iterated is divisible by every single number in `arrRange`. Effectively, this means that there are 2 arrays that are both getting iterated against each other?

How would I go about accomplishing this?

Comment: Stop using `var` inside your function.

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine, why?

Answer (score 0):

First, find the LCM of all elements of the array:

```
int gcd(int a, int b) { 
    if (b == 0) return a; 
    return gcd(b, a % b); 
}       

int lcm_array(int arr[], int n) { 
    int lcm = arr[0];       
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        lcm = (arr[i] * lcm) / gcd(arr[i], lcm);
    }
    return lcm; 
}
```

Then, iterate through the array and check if any division between the lcm and an element is odd. If it is, multiply the lcm by 2 and move on until you finish:

```
int arr[] = { ... };
int lcm = lcm_array(arr, arr_size);
for(int i = 0; i < arr_size; i++){
    if( (lcm / arr[i]) % 2 == 1 ) lcm *= 2;
}
print(lcm);
```

Comment: Java is not JavaScript.

Comment: The main point is the algorithm and not the language. Also, this is pseudocode/C++.

Comment: Maybe mention that in your answer, since the OP tagged their question with `javascript` and provided code in that language.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he can understand that if he knows javascript, there is nothing language-specific in the answer, almost everything written can be fast-forwarded to javascript, I just pasted what I wrote in the compiler, since I understood that the algorithm is the issue. Anyway, OP is free to accept any other answer better than this.

Answer (score 0):

Your game plan would not be efficient. The question asked really translates to finding the least common multiple (LCM) of all the numbers in the range (including the two input values).

The LCM operation is associative, and follows [this rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple#Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic):

> If none of *a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, … , a<sub>r</sub>* is zero, then
>
> *lcm(a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, … , a<sub>r</sub>) = lcm(lcm(a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, … , a<sub>r-1</sub>), a<sub>r</sub>)*.

So this means that you can calculate *lcm(a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>)* as a first result, then use that to process the next value: *lcm(result, a<sub>3</sub>)*, ...etc. This is what is called *reducing* the range of numbers by the LCM operation, and so this algorithm really is a good candidate for using the [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method:

```js
const gcd = (a, b) => b ? gcd(b, a % b) : a; 
const lcm = (a, b) => a * b / gcd(a, b);
const range = (a, b) => Array.from({length: b - a}, (_, i) => a + i);

const smallestCommons = ([a, b]) => 
    range(Math.min(a, b), Math.max(a, b) + 1).reduce(lcm);

// Run it:
console.log(smallestCommons([23, 18])); // 6056820
```

For the functions that define `gcd` and `lcm`, see [Wikipedia on lcm using gcd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple#Using_the_greatest_common_divisor) and [on the recursive version of the Eucledian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Implementations)

For creating a range, [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) is used. The `range` function uses it to generate an array *[a, a+1, ..., b-1]*, so excluding *b*.

I have used arrow function notation, as in the end each function body is just one expression.

### Basic

If you are not used to arrow functions, destructuring, reducing, and/or recursion, then here is a version with simple JavaScript constructs only:

```js
function gcd(a, b) { // iterative implementation
    while (b != 0) {
        let t = b;
        b = a % b;
        a = t;
    }
    return a;
}

function lcm(a, b) {
    return a * b / gcd(a, b);
}

function smallestCommons(rng) { 
    if (rng[0] > rng[1]) {
        rng.reverse();
    }
    let a = rng[0];
    let b = rng[1];
    let result = a;
    for (let i = a; i <= b; i++) {
        result = lcm(result, i);
    }
    return result;
}

// Run it:
console.log(smallestCommons([23, 18])); // 6056820
```

Comment: My game plan is definitely not be efficient... but would it work if I manged to execute it?

Comment: It would work, but for large ranges it would get slow.

Answer (score 0):

```
function smallestCommons(arr) {
  
  arr = arr.sort((a,b)=>a-b);
 
  
  let result = [];
  for(let i=arr[0];i<=arr[1];i++){
    result.push(i);
  }

  console.log(result);

  let i=1;
  let rr;
  while(result.every(item=>rr%item==0)==false){
    i++;
    rr = arr[1]*i; 
  }

 console.log(rr);

 return rr;
}



smallestCommons([1,13]);
```